# Can I use Object Initialiser syntax for base constructor somehow?

Tags: c#, syntax, object-initializers

You can use this to quickly instantiate class' properties with values you'd like:

```
Form myform = new Form
{
    Width = 500,
    Height = 150,
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
    Text = "Hello world!",
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
};
```

But this below is an invalid syntax:

```
class MyForm: Form
{
    public MyForm(string caption) : base() {
            Width = 500,
            Height = 150,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
            Text = caption,
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen}
    {

    }
}
```

So I wonder if there's a way to do it, or if I just have to do it old-school, like this:

```
class MyForm: Form
{
    public MyForm(string caption) : base()
    {
        Width = 500;
        Height = 150;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        Text = caption;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    }
}
```

I admit it's not such a terrible difference, but still I'm interested for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: Object initializers are just syntactic sugar, if you check the compiled assembly's IL using ILSpy, you'll see they're separate statements anyway.

Comment: What's the sense of adding two additional curve brackets? :)

Comment: No there isn't. Just do it the "old-school" way.

Comment: You are not using base constructor by the way (I mean what you are trying to do is not related to base constructor at all).